# If I burn a compound, it gives a specific color. So can I find out the elements of the compound using that color it burns with?

Tags: physical-chemistry

For example NaCl burns with yellow-orange colour. So can I find out the elements of the compound using that color(Assuming that I don't know the compound)?

Comment: Yes and no. If you put NaCl into a flame, like I did [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678), you will get the familiar yellow sodium D lines emission. More generally, though, you need to do spectroscopy, e.g., atomic emission spectroscopy or atomic absorption spectroscopy. Flame tests are too crude and not quantitative. As well, the chlorine from the NaCl will not significantly emit visible light (from excited chlorine atoms de-exciting). And note that sodium is an easy element compared to, e.g., uranium: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/175028/79678.

Comment: @EdV I was going to post an answer, but I think you should do it instead.

Comment: There are a number of related relevant questions here, and answers too, e.g., https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/168454/79678. Search at this stack exchange for “flame test” and related terms. Several people here, e.g., @AChem, have posted good answers to relevant queries.

Comment: Some elements give very distinct flame colours. But many do not and distinguishing mixtures by colour is not remotely easy without proper instruments that look at the full spectrum of emission lines in the flame.

Comment: I wonder what colour osmium + O2 would produce